# Fixed field of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ over $\big\lbrace \operatorname{Id}, \sigma^3, \sigma^6, \sigma^9 \big\rbrace$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

What is the fixed field of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ (as extension over $\mathbb{Q}$) over $H := \big\lbrace \operatorname{Id}, \sigma^3, \sigma^6, \sigma^9 \big\rbrace \leq S_3$ where $\sigma : \xi \mapsto \xi^2$ and $\xi = e^\frac{2\pi i}{13}$?

---

What I've done so far:

I first determined the permutation table for $\xi$ over $\sigma$:

|  | $\operatorname{Id}$ | $\sigma$ | $\sigma^2$ | $\sigma^3$ | $\sigma^4$ | $\sigma^5$ | $\sigma^6$ | $\sigma^7$ | $\sigma^8$ | $\sigma^9$ | $\sigma^{10}$ | $\sigma^{11}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\xi$ | $\xi$ | $\xi^2$ | $\xi^4$ | $\xi^8$ | $\xi^3$ | $\xi^6$ | $\xi^{12}$ | $\xi^{11}$ | $\xi^9$ | $\xi^5$ | $\xi^{10}$ | $\xi^{7}$ |

Then I calculated the fixed field for every element of $H$ (by comparing linear combination scalars):

| $\operatorname{Id}$ | $\sigma^3$ | $\sigma^6$ | $\sigma^9$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ | $\mathbb{Q}(\xi^2 + \xi^3 + \xi^{10} + \xi^{11}, \xi^4 + \xi^6 + \xi^7 + \xi^9)$ | $\mathbb{Q}(\xi^2 + \xi^{11}, \xi^3 + \xi^{10}, \xi^4 + \xi^9, \xi^5 + \xi^8 + \xi^6 + \xi^7)$ | $\mathbb{Q}(\xi^2 + \xi^{10} + \xi^{11} + \xi^3, \xi^4 + \xi^7 + \xi^9 + \xi^6)$ |

I'm not sure how to continue from here; is the entire fixed field just the intersection of these smaller ones?

---

If my above hypothesis is true, is it also true in general? i.e. is
$$\mathbb{L}^H = \bigcap_{\sigma \in H} \mathbb{L}^\sigma$$

for any Galois extension $\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}$ and a subgroup of the Galois group $H \leq \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K})$ true?

My intuition tells me it is true. However, I do not know how I would prove it formally. Would I use the definition of a fixed field $\mathbb{L}^H = \big\lbrace x \in \mathbb{L} \mid \sigma(x) = x \quad \forall \sigma \in H \big\rbrace$ and argue that if it's in the intersection then it's fiexd by all elements of $H$?

*I've now moved this hypothesis into [a separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616319/943349)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any integer $k\in[0,12],$ $\sigma^3(\xi^k)=\xi^{8k\bmod{13}}=\xi^{\sigma(k)}$ where $\sigma=(1\;8\;12\;5)(2\;3\;11\;10)(4\;6\;9\;7)$ hence the subfield fixed by $\sigma^3$ is
$$K=\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$
where
$$\alpha=\xi+\xi^8+\xi^{12}+\xi^5,\;\beta=\xi^2+\xi^3+\xi^{11}+\xi^{10},\;\gamma=\xi^4+\xi^6+\xi^9+\xi^7.$$
But $1+\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\xi^k=0$ hence e.g. $\gamma$ can be eliminated, so $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta).$ And $\beta=-\alpha^2-2\alpha+2$ can also be eliminated. Finally,
$$K=\Bbb Q(\alpha).$$
The subfield fixed by $H$ is the same, since every number fixed by $\sigma^3$ is fixed by any power of it.

Edit:

- The relation $\beta=-\alpha^2-2\alpha+2$ was found by squaring $\alpha$ and grouping the various powers of $\xi$:$$\alpha^2=\beta+2\gamma+4=\beta+2(-1-\alpha-\beta)+4=-2\alpha+2-\beta.$$
- The same method allows to compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$:$$\alpha^3=\alpha(-2\alpha+2-\beta)=-2\alpha^2+2\alpha-(\alpha+2\beta+\gamma)$$$$=-2\alpha^2+2\alpha-\beta+1=-\alpha^2+4\alpha-1.$$

Comment: This is nice, and makes the argument transparent, +1. An alternative is to observe that $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta\neq\alpha$, so $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not fixed by $\sigma$. As $\langle\sigma^3\rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ we can deduce that $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\xi)/\Bbb{Q}(\alpha))=\langle \sigma^3\rangle$, and the claim follows from the properties of Galois correspondence.

Comment: The way you wrote $\beta=r(\alpha)$, $r(x)=-x^2-2x+2$ allows us to write $\gamma=r(\beta)$, implying that $\alpha$ is a zero of $q(x)=r(r(x))+r(x)+x+1=-3+11x+x^2-4x^3-x^4$. We know that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must be a cubic, so this must have a rational root, and testing reveals it to be $-3$. So
$$q(x)=-(x+3)(x^3+x^2-4x+1),$$ where the cubic factor must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Sorry about running with this, I can't stop :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wow! I had found that minimal polynomial by a less elegant method. I edited.