# Fixed field of entire subgroup is intersection of each element's fixed field; $\mathbb{L}^H = \bigcap_{\sigma \in H} \mathbb{L}^\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

This question originates from [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615828/fixed-field-of-mathbbq-xi-over-big-lbrace-operatornameid-sigma3).

Let $\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}$ be a Galois extension. Let $H$ be a subgroup of its Galois group. The intermediate field corresponding to $H$ is its fixed field $$\mathbb{L}^H := \big\lbrace x \in \mathbb{L} \mid \sigma(x) = x \quad \forall \sigma \in H \big\rbrace$$ We define $$\mathbb{L}^\sigma := \big\lbrace x \in \mathbb{L} \mid \sigma(x) = x \big\rbrace$$ for any $\sigma \in H$.

Do we have $$\mathbb{L}^H = \bigcap_{\sigma \in H} \mathbb{L}^\sigma$$?

---

I tried coming up with a proof:

"$\subseteq$": Let $x \in \mathbb{L}^H$ then for all $\sigma \in H$ we know that $\sigma(x) = x$, therefore $x \in \mathbb{L}^\sigma$, and thus $x \in \bigcap_{\sigma \in H} \mathbb{L}^\sigma$

"$\supseteq$": Analog to $\subseteq$; let $x \in \bigcap_{\sigma \in H} \mathbb{L}^\sigma$ then $\sigma(x) = x$ for all $\sigma \in H$, therefore $x \in \mathbb{L}^H$.

This proof seems "too easy to be true" to me, though it looks correct.

Comment: Could you put words in the title? I often search for words like "find the fixed field of ...",and I think the question can be more helpful if more people is able to find it.

Comment: Sure thing! Is it good like this?

Comment: Yes, thanks! It may look a silly thing, but it helps when you are looking for old answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true. $x \in \cap_{\sigma \in H} L^\sigma$ iff $x \in L^\sigma$ for all $\sigma \in H$, iff $\sigma(x) = x$ for all $\sigma \in H$, iff $x \in L^H$.